# Form data being overwritten in second POST?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have two forms embedded in a webpage which edit a mySQL database. The first form ("add.php") allows the user to input a name and add it to the database. Then when reloading the webpage, the table is built from all of the data in the database. The second form allows a user to delete from the database by clicking a cell in the table corresponding to that row.

Here's the relevant part of the index.php file:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','[username]','[pwd]','tablename');
            $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM tablename");
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                echo "<tr class=\"row100 body\">
                    <td class=\"cell100 column1\">".$row['name']."</td>
                    <td class=\"cell100 column2\">
                        <form id=\"delete\" action=\"delete.php\" method=\"post\">
                            <input form=\"delete\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"dname\" value=\"".$row['name']."\" />
                            <input form=\"delete\" type=\"submit\" value=\"X\" />
                        </form>
                    </td>";
            }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell100 column1">
                <form id="add" action="insert.php" method="post">
                    <input form="add" type="text" name="name" value="Name" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td class="cell100 column2"><input form="add" type="submit" value="Add to list" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue is that no matter what row I click on to delete, it always deletes the most-recently added one. When I inspect the row, the correct value is stored in the delete form; however, echoing the value that gets received by delete.php (dname) reveals the wrong name.

Any ideas what might be going wrong here? Is there an easier way to do this than passing the name to delete into a field in the table to store it for the delete form?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Instead of using a whole new form and a POST, I replaced the delete form with

`<a href=\"delete.php?dname=".$row['name']."\">X</a>`

and then the delete.php code to use GET instead of POST.